# Can I use 'contributed' with 'were', and do I need 'the' before 'Islamic Era'?

Tags: verbs, definite-article, existentials

Which sentence is grammatically correct?

> 1. There were many factors contributed to the decline of Islamic Era.
> 2. There were many factors contributing to the decline of **the** Islamic Era.

Can I use 'contributed' as a verb with 'were'? The second question is do I need to use 'the' before 'Islamic Era'? Which online tool is best for sentence checking?

Regards;

Comment: We need to know what research you have done before we can give you a useful answer. Can you tell us why you think _"There were many factors contributed to the decline of Islamic Era"_ might be a valid sentence in English? What do _you_ think about the definite article in your second sentence? (Many make the claim, but there is no magical website that will correct your writing. To communicate in any language, you must learn it.)

Comment: Regarding the use of *the*: yes, you need to use "the".  *Era* is a countable noun, and there are many possible eras, of which the Islamic is just one; you need to use an article here because you're talking about a specific era.

Comment: @ P.E. Dant, i do not have any detail research on English. Iam learning different words ti improve vocabulary. I wanted to write the sentence in Past Simple so i try to use contributed as a verb and in the second form but i was confused as were is also used as a past tense.  Can you please highlight why it is grammatically incorrect and what are the rules in situation.

Comment: There is no need to offer a bounty. Please see @stangdon's comment above. In English, there are _countable_ and _uncountable_ nouns. _Era_ is countable, so it should take the definite article in _both_ sentences. The first sentence includes a  _restrictive clause,_ using the participle _contributed_ to describe the factors. This clause needs the _relative pronoun_ "that" to introduce it: _"There were many factors **that** contributed to the decline of **the** Islamic Era."_ We are not talking about just _any_ factors: we restrict the factors to the ones _that contributed_ to the decline.